# MacBook Pro 2015 - new battery temperature - 33-40C in usage mode

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

After replacing the battery on my 15" 2015 MacBook Pro, I noticed a slight increase in battery temperature. (*2 days with new battery, 3 cycle*)
I checked the temperature by CocountBattery. Ambient temperature 24 °C (75 °F)

- In operation mode (VS Code, YouTube, Postman etc) with MagSafe disabled: 33-35 °C (91-95 °F)
- In 1 % to 20 % charge mode: Battery temperature has risen to 41 °C (106 °F)
- In idle mode, the temperature is about: 29-31 °C

Apple's website describes temperatures above 30 °C (86 °F) damage the battery.

Is my battery normal or should I replace it again? What is the normal battery temperature for my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Apple website describes the ***ambient temperature*** outside the computer: i.e. the weather.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201640
*(This says "Use your Mac notebook where the ambient temperature is between 50° and 95° F (10° and 35° C).")*

If the outside is too hot, then the laptop cannot cool itself, because there's insufficient heat gradient.

It is expected that the internals of your laptop will get hot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, what is the normal battery temperature?

Comment: I have never stopped to check the battery's temperature in 20 years. Quit Coconut Battery, or whatever, and enjoy your laptop!

Comment: But the question remains open, what is considered the norm :)